# Why does this recursive function still cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow

Why does this recursive function still cause a stack overflow?

```
void DrawSierpinskiTriangle(const Point2f& left, const Point2f& top, const Point2f& right)
{

    if (right.x - left.x <= 100)
    {
        return;
    }

    DrawTriangle(left, top, right);

    SetColor(0, 1, 0);
    DrawSierpinskiTriangle(Point2f{ right.x / 4.f,top.y / 2.f }, top, Point2f{ right.x / 4.f * 3,top.y / 2.f });

    SetColor(0, 0, 1);
    DrawSierpinskiTriangle(Point2f{ right.x / 2,left.y }, Point2f{ right.x / 4.f * 3,top.y / 2.f }, right);

    SetColor(1, 0, 0);
    DrawSierpinskiTriangle(left, Point2f{ top.x / 2.f,top.y / 2.f }, Point2f{ top.x,left.y });

}
```

Comment: What prevents you from adding simple debug statements showing the parameters of each recursive call, thus showing which values are infinitely recursing?

Comment: You are getting a stack overflow because right.x - left.x never gets to be less than or equal to 100 within the limit of the number of stacks that can be handled.

Comment: *still cause a stack overflow?* -- When you say "still cause", does that mean it was causing a stack overflow before, you made changes, and the stack overflow is still occurring?  If so, then maybe the changes you made didn't fix the issue, and you need to revisit those changes.

Comment: To make you ask a question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of problems in the posted recursion scheme.

- The termination condition assumes that the point `right` is always at the right of point `left` and that the "bottom" edge (the one that connects those two points) is not vertical. Those may or may not be part of the unmentioned preconditions.
- The transformations used to calculate the coordinates passed to the recursive calls are wrong. They might have been correct for a particular first step, but not in general.

  We need to find out the **midpoints** of the edges of the triangles, which depend on the points passed to the function.

  ```
  #include <numeric>      // std::midpoint

  Point2f midpoint(Point2f const& a, Point2f const& b)
  {
      // See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint
      return {std::midpoint(a.x, b.x), std::midpoint(a.y, b.y)};
  }

  void DrawSierpinskiTriangle(const Point2f& left, const Point2f& top, const Point2f& right)
  {
      // Ok, let's assume that the bottom edge is horizontal
      if ( right.x - left.x <= 100)
      {
          return;
      }

      auto a{ midpoint(left, top) };  
      auto b{ midpoint(top, right) };  
      auto c{ midpoint(right, left) };

      // ...

      // Top
      DrawSierpinskiTriangle(a, top, b);

      // Bottom right
      DrawSierpinskiTriangle(c, b, right);

      // Bottom left
      DrawSierpinskiTriangle(left, a, c); 
  }
  ```

  [Example.](https://godbolt.org/z/a3o37E)